# Angularjs adds a slash to anchor links

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor

How to prevent angularjs from adding slash to anchor links?

Ex. 
http://examples.com/examples#example1

will be turned into 
http://examples.com/examples#/example1

as soon as the page loads.

Please note the slash (/) after # sign.

The later link then disables the anchor function in html.

Comment: Here are a few links to check out. [scotch.io](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) and [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score -2):

There is only one hack without adding a directive for this purpose:

```
<a href="#scroll#example1">Scroll to first Example</a>
```

The first hash tag will get the unwanted slash, but the second will work like a default anchor link. The title (in this case "scroll") of the first hash tag does not have any consequences for this functionality. It's just semantics. Feel free to put whatever you want.